# Get current timezone in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, timezone, twig, twig-extension

Is there any way to get current timezone in Twig templates rather than passing from crontroller. [This link](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html#timezone) gives the date for a specific timezone.

```
{{ post.published_at|date("m/d/Y", "Europe/Paris") }}
```

Comment: [Chain](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twig/4923/extending-twig/17380/adding-custom-filters-functions#t=201610311432400858658) the method `date_default_timezone_get()` in Twig with a `Twig_SimpleFunction`

Comment: the timezone of the current logged user?

Comment: @Matteo Yes, the current timezone of the logged user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try a JS solution, like moment.js. You can assign a special CSS class (eg. date-transform) and run a script on all elements with this class:

```
$('.date-transform').each(function(){
        var initialDate = moment($(this).html(), 'MMMM D, YYYY HH:mm');
        if (initialDate.isValid()) {
            var offset = moment().utcOffset(); // this is the client UTC offset
            var finalDate = initialDate.add(offset, 'minutes').format('MMMM D, YYYY HH:mm');
            $(this).html(finalDate);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Good One. Getting an console error **Uncaught ReferenceError: dateFormat is not defined**

Comment: var dateFormat = ''MMMM D, YYYY HH:mm';
or whatever format your date is displayed in

Comment: Updated the answer